# Orthogonal projection matrix affecting z-buffer on one device

Tags: android, opengl-es2

I am experimenting using `Matrix.orthoM` for a isometric projection, rather than `Matrix.frustumM`.

On one device, the z buffering does not appear to be working correctly and I get a cut away effect seen below on the wheels in particular. Both devices work fine with frustum projection.

Sorry not much to go on, just hoping someone will just be able to take one look and recognise the problem.

Sony Xperia Z:

[image: On Sony Xperia Z]

LG P920:

[image: On LG P920]

Sony Xperia Z:

[image: On Sony Xperia Z]

LG P920:

[image: On LG P920]

Answer (score 2):

It was a near and far problem. I had way too large a range 2 near, 24000 far.

The high res of the one device highlighted the problem.

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Buffer_Precision